# Compile Assembler Source fail in msys2

Tags: c++

When I compile a project in MSYS,

An assembler source looks like:

```
.file "a.S"
.text
.globl jump_fcontext
.type jump_fcontext,@function
.align 16
jump_fcontext:
.size jump_fcontext,.-jump_fcontext
.section .note.GNU-stack,"",%progbits
```

Use command line "clang -c a.S", some error occure:

```
a.S:4:7: error: expected absolute expression
.type jump_fcontext,@function
      ^
a.S:7:1: error: unknown directive
.size jump_fcontext,.-jump_fcontext
^
a.S:8:19: error: unexpected token in directive
.section .note.GNU-stack,"",%progbits
                  ^
```

clang is
clang version 11.0.0 (https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages ca391a3660d17cdee1e94d5afd2e72a4f750cddb)

But I compile this S file in Ubuntu, it compile OK.

How can I compile this S file in MSYS2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> a.S:4:7: error: expected absolute expression
> .type jump_fcontext,@function
>       ^
> a.S:7:1: error: unknown directive
> .size jump_fcontext,.-jump_fcontext
> ^
> ```

According to the [manual of (an older version of?) the GNU assembler](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas-2.9.1/html_chapter/as_7.html), the `.size` and `.type` directives have a different meaning when used with the `COFF` file format (which is required to build Windows `.exe` files) and when using the `ELF` file format (which is required to build Linux executables).

As a result, you cannot use `.type` and `.size` the same way in Windows and Linux. However, both directives seem only to be used for debugging information. Simply removing these two lines should be possible.

> ```
> a.S:8:19: error: unexpected token in directive
> .section .note.GNU-stack,"",%progbits
>                   ^
> ```

Obviously, the assembler has problems with section names containing a minus sign.

However, the `.note.GNU-stack` section is a special section that tells the linker for **Linux** how to create the executable file. The linker for Windows seems to ignore this section if it should be present.

So you can also leave out this line if you compile for Windows.

And yes:

Assembler is not only CPU-dependent, but also OS dependent!